# PFQuery to load objects stored in an array in a PFObject into a PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a `PFQueryTableViewController` which loads `Thread`s (PFObjects with data about a forum thread) just fine.

When a cell is pressed, a new `PFQuertyTableViewController` loads `Response`s (PFObjects with data about a user's response on the thread), but I am having trouble making sure they are `Response`s specific to that `Thread`.

I can get the entire array of responses very easily,

```
NSArray *responses = thread[@"responses"];
```

However, I have no idea how to use this with a `PFQuery` in a `PFQueryTableViewController`. Here's what I tried:

I got this idea from [this forum post](https://www.parse.com/questions/populate-a-pfquerytableviewcontroller-from-an-array-ios), but it doesn't do anything for me (self.objects is empty).

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    NSArray *threads = self.topic[@"threads"];
    for (PFObject *thread in threads)
    {
        [thread fetchIfNeeded];
        NSLog(@"Thread title: %@", thread[@"title"]);
    }
    [query whereKey:@"title" containedIn:threads];
    return query;
}
```

Output:

```
Thread title: This is my title for my post about "Animal Rights"
2014-06-20 10:25:11.730 ThumbWar[9185:60b] Fetched: <Thread:dasLkCUo77:(null)> {
    title = "This is my title for my post about \"Animal Rights\"";
    user = "<PFUser:********>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [includeKey](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-relational/iOS) when you get Threads in your first `PFQueryTableViewController`. Threads will come with their Responses and you can pass these Responses to a normal `UITableViewController` when the cell is clicked.

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query includeKey:@"responses"]; //Retrieve responses of threads
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"]; //You may also sort Threads if you want 
    return query;
}
```

Comment: What if you weren't doing a prior query for Threads? What if you're starting with nothing but a Thread objectID, and you want to get create one query that gets that Thread's Responses for a PFQueryTableViewController?